# Excel VBA macro truncating cell value in HTMLBody Replace

Tags: vba, excel

So I've run into a strange situation with VBA in Excel.

Long story short, I've written a macro that generates an email (from Excel), from a template, then uses `Replace` with `.HTMLBody` in order to push some info from my Excel doc into the email.

So I've got a table in Excel that basically has 4 columns and can have between 1 and 50 rows of data. It's that formatted table that I need in an email. I played around initially with trying to copy to clipboard and pasting, but it seemed easier to just recreate the table in HTML, then concatenate all of the HTML with my values, then pass that one cell into the correct space on the email body.

This works great in most cases, however, when there are more than about 9 rows of data, the HTML that gets passed into the email is cut off.

I thought initially that maybe my one large concatenated cell was too large for Excel, but it's not. I confirmed that even in cases with lots of rows, all of the values, including their inline CSS for the table formatting are correctly represented in the single cell.

So, I wrote some code that spits out the value of my one massive concatenated cell using this:

```
` DEBUG TO SAVE HTML BODY TO TEXT FILE
Dim s As String
Dim n As Integer
n = FreeFile()
Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.txt" For Output As #n
s = Worksheets("ACTIONS").Range("$AA$201").Text
Debug.Print s 
Print #n, s 
Close #n
```

This is great since it allows me to see exactly what is getting passed into my Outlook body. After investigating, I've found is that the length of this code will max out at `8222` characters.

This is odd because the value should be about 20,000 characters (I just copy and pasted the cell value itself straight from Excel into a code editor and checked the length).

This tells me that there's some Excel issue that perhaps it's just going to quickly to process all 20k characters, and it stops after ~8k?

Because the code is being truncated, my formatted table ends up all screwed up because the `<table>` tag never gets closed, etc.

....

Why would Excel have an issue replacing approximately 20k characters? It seemingly stops at 8k no matter what, which leads me to believe the macro is just moving on before it's done. Can I add a pause or something to give it time to fully process, or do you not think that will help?

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be not to store the whole HTML in one cell. Instead, you can just build .HTMLbody. Try to inspire with this:

```
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim s As String
Dim mI As MailItem
Dim r As Range
Set rng = Selection

with mI
.htmlBody = "<table>"
For Each r In rng.Rows
    .htmlBody = .htmlBody & vbNewLine & "<tr>"
    For Each cl In r.Cells
        .htmlBody = .htmlBody & "<th>" & cl.Value & "</th>"
    Next cl
    .htmlBody = .htmlBody & vbNewLine & "</tr>"
Next r
.htmlBody = htmlBody & "</table>"
end with
End Sub
```

This code will build your table row by row. Of course, you should set rng range in some more elaborated way, I just use selection for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Playing around with this idea now. Will followup and see if I can get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd respond to myself since I figured out how to solve it in a bit of an unsavory manner.  For those finding this, MarcinSzaleniec's answer is likely the right approach if you're writing a macro and have this issue.

With that being said, I added a single line to have VBA do the concatenation of the HTML from my table, instead of relying on the Excel formula:

```
responsetable = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("AA10:AA200")), "")
```

Where `responsetable` was inserted into my email through the `replace` function:

```
Replace(.htmlBody, "#responsetable#", responsetable)
```